# How to auto refresh ElasticsearchContext on CRUD operation?

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I have an ElasticsearchContext of my data. I am using ElasticsearchCRUD package for asp.net. When I perform any CRUD operation it does not refresh the context automatically. For that I need to refresh my browser.

Is there any way I can auto refresh my context.

We can use `ElasticClient.Refresh()` while using NEST.

Any ideas about ElasticsearchCRUD?